# Python: convert string to date was failed in float datatype using dict zip

Tags: python

I would like to convert string to date. the converter are use 'm' for a minute, 'h' for an hour and 'd' for a day. for instance: '1d3h50m'.
It has a correct answer if I put the exact number, but the problem that it will be wrong if I use float number. for example: '1.5d3h50m'.

Here is my script:

```
import re

def compute_time(hour_string):
    numbers = [int(i) for i in re.split('d|h|m|s', hour_string) if i != '']
    words = [i for i in re.split('\d', hour_string) if i != '']

    combined = dict(zip(words, numbers))

    return combined.get('d', 0) * 86400 + combined.get('h', 0) * 3600 + combined.get('m', 0) * 60 + combined.get('s', 0)

print compute_time('1.5h15m5s')
```

Could someone tell me how to make this work?

Comment: Seems weird allowing that format... Surely `1.5h15m` should really be `1h45m`... allowing stuff like `1.5241341425h` just seems odd... :p

Comment: Actually I use this for the engineering data. yes, it looks weird. but it happens. and also somehow the date will be only '1.5h' . btw thanks for comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the datatype from `int` to `float`.

```
numbers = [float(i) for i in re.split('d|h|m|s', hour_string) if i != '']
```

And i suggest you to change your code like below.

```
def compute_time(hour_string):
    numbers = [float(i) for i in re.split('d|h|m|s', hour_string) if i != '']
    words = [i for i in re.split(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', hour_string) if i != '']
    combined = dict(zip(words, numbers))
    return combined.get('d', 0) * 86400 + combined.get('h', 0) * 3600 + combined.get('m', 0) * 60 + combined.get('s', 0)

print compute_time('1.6h15m5s')
```

`re.split(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', hour_string)` would split the input string according to the number. If you split your input according to `\d` then you will get `.` as output.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out, you can use `float` instead of `int`, but that leads to some weird combinations of what you can do. I'd also simplify to find stuff up until valid `dhms` as pairs, then sum over those, eg:

```
def compute_time(text):
    scale = {'d': 86400, 'h': 3600, 'm': 60, 's': 1}
    return sum(float(n) * scale[t] for n, t in re.findall('(.*?)([dhms])', text))
```